# Open gnome-terminal in background from Java

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I'm trying to open gnome-terminal to execute a command from Java by the following code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"gnome-terminal", "-e", "command"});
```

But this code will show terminal for user, how I can open gnome-terminal in background?

Comment: why you need to open terminal ???? Do you need to execute the command???

Comment: If I ran the command without opening gnome-terminal it does not work as expected, I ran "saned -d128" command to send and read bytes.

Comment: You can use `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` for executing the command instead of `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to open a terminal visually to execute a command. Shell interpreter is a program which you can invoke without the terminal window. What terminal window does is it just sends what you type on the terminal, interacts with the underlying shell interpreter and gives you the results. When you need to run a OS specific command you would want to directly call the shell interpreter you want to with(i.e bash, csh, ksh) and get the result from within the Java program.

Working with commands and reading output from them is not that easy sometimes. So I would suggest you to have a look at [Apache Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) which will ease reading data from externally invoked program.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer helped a lot.